# How to write and update .txt files with python?

Tags: python, bitcoin

I ve written a script that fetches bitcoin data and saves it in .txt files or in the case where the .txt files exist, it updates them. The .txt files are nodes and relationships connecting the nodes for neo4j.

At the beginning of the script:

1. It checks whether the files exist, so it opens them and appends new lines OR
2. In case the files do not exist, the script creates them and starts appending lines.

The .txt files are constantly open, the script writes the new data. The .txt files close when all the data are written or I terminate the execution.

My question is:

Should I open, write, close  each .txt file for each iteration and for each .txt file?

or

Should I keep it the way it is now; open the .txt files, do all the writing, when the writing is done close the .txt file

I am saving data from 6013 blocks. Which way would minimize risk of corrupting the data written in the .txt files?

Comment: do you need to overwrite the file every time, or you are just writing to the end of the file?

Comment: What's redundant for small files and short-lived programs may be crucial for large files and long-running programs. "Most efficient" seems like the wrong question to ask here anyway. By what metric do you mean?

Comment: depends if you care about another concurrent version of the code running, or this one crashing...  sounds like you should think about using a relational database, they can be good for this sort of thing

Comment: @בנימיןכהן I need to write at the end of the file. Loss of data previously written is not an option.

Comment: @tripleee I quote a part of my question:

"Which way would minimize risk of producing any error related to the way the data is written.". 

What I mean is which way gives higher probability of not corrupting the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping files open will be faster. In the comments you mentioned that "Loss of data previously written is not an option". The probability of corrupting files is higher for open files so open and close file on each iteration is more reliable.
There is also an option to keep data in some buffer and to write/append buffer to file  when all data is received or on user/system interrupt or network timeout.

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for but I didn't phrase the question correctly I guess.

What I am doing right now is I set a time of 20 sec which serves multiple purposes one of which is to give me time to terminate the script every 100 blocks of written data. Therefore txt files are closed and the data stored.

I'm planning on changing the script to what you are suggesting. However, there is a trade off between execution time and probability of ending up with corrupted files.

Answer (score -1):

I think keeping the file open will be more efficient, because python won't need to search for the file and open it every time you want to read/write the file.

I guess it should look like this

```
with open(filename, "a") as file:
    while True:
        data = # get data
        file.write(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Run a benchmark and see for yourself would the typical answer for this kind of question.

Nevertheless opening and closing a file does have a cost. Python needs to allocate memory for the buffer and data structures associated with the file and call some operating system functions, e.g. the [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) syscall which in turn would search the file in cache or on disk.

On the other hand there is a limit on the number of files a program, the user, the whole system, etc can open at the same time. For example on Linux, the value in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` denotes the maximum number of file-handles that the kernel will allocate. When you get lots of error messages about running out of file handles, you might want to increase this limit ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt)).
If your program runs in such a restrictive environment then it would be good to keep the file open only when needed.